Why do I receive "SESSION_REVOKED" after some time in my web Telegram-A fork?
I'm working on a fork of Telegram (specifically, Telegram-tt) and encountering an issue where my session gets revoked (SESSION_REVOKED) after some time.
Here are the details:
I am deploying the fork on a VPS server and have a duplicate on Vercel
The session initially connects successfully, but it gets revoked without any specific user action after some time.
Questions:
Are there specific configurations or security settings I might be missing that cause this session revocation?
Could it be due to Telegram's session policies for unofficial clients or forks?
Are there any known solutions or best practices to prevent SESSION_REVOKED errors in Telegram's forks?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! 
